# How does a bittorent peer accquires info dictionary when magnet URI is provided?

Tags: java, p2p, bittorrent, dht

In a magnet URI scheme, a URI contains info hash, trackers and peers. With info hash we can obtain peers from tracker(tracker protocol).

My question is: How can a client obtain complete info hash dictionary with provided peers and info hash? I digged in a little, it uses messages from extension protocol? But does it contact remote peer for info dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

A client/peer that is feed a magnet-URI will connect to the trackers in the URI and/or use the DHT to get a *peer-list*.
Then it will start to connect to the peers.
When it is connected to a peer/peers, it will first start to download the *info-dict* using *BEP9 - Extension for Peers to Send Metadata Files*.
Then it will start to download the files in the torrent.

Comment: Can you direct me into how to use BEP9(except of documentation). Implementation or something.